# org.hibernate.HibernateException [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I know that may that question has been asked before, but the difference for my question is that I am using **extended PersistenceUnit** and also I am not the one who manages the transaction as the server is responsible for managing it.

BTW I am using JPA(2.1) with hibernate(4.3.10) provider, PostgreSQL(9.5) DB and liberty server

This is what I get in the browser
[image]

And here are my entities in simple view

```
@Entity
public class GeoArea{
      private Integer id;//Auto Generated
      private String name;

      private Set<TourismOrganization> organizations;

      //getter and setter methods

      @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "geoAreas")
      public Set<TourismOrganization> getOrganizations() {
          return organizations;
      }

       public void setOrganizations(Set<TourismOrganization> organizations) {
           this.organizations = organizations;
       }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class TourismOrganization{
      private Integer id;//Auto Generated
      private String name;

      private BinaryContent logo;
      private Set<TourismGeoArea> geoAreas;

      //other getter and setter methods

      @ManyToMany
      public Set<TourismGeoArea> getGeoAreas() {
          return geoAreas;
      }

      public void setGeoAreas(Set<TourismGeoArea> geoAreas) {
         this.geoAreas = geoAreas;
      }

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, orphanRemoval = true)
      public BinaryContent getLogo() {
          return logo;
      }

      public void setLogo(BinaryContent logo) {
          this.logo = logo;
      }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class BinaryContent{
    private Integer id;//Auto Generated
    private String contentType;

    private byte[] data;

    //other getter and setter methods

    @Lob
    @Column(length = 16000000) // This should generate a medium blob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // I've read this is default, but anyway...
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

**Any Idea how to solve this problem when getting organizations under geoArea by using >> geoArea.organizations in xhtml page?**

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was asked before one month ago, but i want to share my solution as no one was answered here to my question.

BTW my solution was to use **byte[]** without **@Lob** over its getter so this will generate the column in postgre database table to be **bytea** and instead of **oid** column any more

Here are my code which i am using now to avoid **Large objects may not be used in auto commit mode ....** exception which was fired in browser and prevent the page from working as expected

```
@Entity
public class BinaryContent{
     private Integer id;//Auto Generated
     private String contentType;

     private byte[] data;

     //other getter and setter methods

     //@Lob >> remember that i am not using it anymore to avoid the exception on the browser
     @Column(length = 16000000) // This should generate a medium blob
     @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // I've read this is default, but anyway...
     public byte[] getData() {
          return data;
     }

     public void setData(byte[] data) {
         this.data = data;
     }

}
```

> Note >> u must delete **oid** column by hand if it was already generated before using **@Lob** if you are using **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update** in your persistence.xml as it will not help to update the column from **oid** to be type **bytea** and it will consider **oid** is fine but sure you can use **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop** to drop and create the tables again and this will generate the column in **bytea** type