# Unable to access lob stream for findByDescriptionContaining(String description)

Tags: java, spring

There is a simple search by string parameter. The page consists of table of DB queries and simple form (input + button). The search slash filter is implemented with addon in Repository and Controller. Template engine is Freemarker.

But if the search input contains existing data it throws an exception `nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream`. Null and non-existent data works correct (showing no queries or all of them respectively).

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class DBFile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    private String description;

    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User creator;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    public DBFile() {
    }

    public DBFile(String fileName, String fileType, String description, byte[] data, User user) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.description = description;
        this.data = data;
        this.creator = user;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public void setFileType(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public User getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(User creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface DBFileRepository extends JpaRepository<DBFile, String> {
    List<DBFile> findByDescriptionContaining(String description);
}
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
    private DBFileRepository dbFileRepository;

@GetMapping("/search")
    public String search(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String search, Model model) {
        Iterable<DBFile> dbFiles;
        if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {
            dbFiles = dbFileRepository.findByDescriptionContaining(search);
        } else {
            dbFiles = dbFileRepository.findAll();
        }
        model.addAttribute("dbFiles", dbFiles);
        return "search";
    }
```

Template

```
<@c.page>

    <form method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" value="${search?ifExists}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="table">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <#list dbFiles as dbFile>
                <tr>
                    <td>${dbFile.fileName}</td>
                    <td>${dbFile.description}</td>
                </tr>
            </#list>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</@c.page>
```

Log

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at ru.tpu.file_java.Application.main(Application.java:9) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110818/method-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgconnection-createclob-is-not-yet-implemented)

Comment: @Compass none of those hints worked, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

After adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true`, I got another exception - `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode`.

But then I found a solution, which worked for me absolutely:
[org.hibernate.HibernateException [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511205/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-large-objec)

Answer (score 7):

Adding @Transactional to your repository may solve the commit issue (worked for me)

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface DBFileRepository extends JpaRepository<DBFile, String> {
    List<DBFile> findByDescription(String description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use findBy match of JpaRepository, the suffix need to be the field that you are trying to get, e.g:

```
@Repository
public interface DBFileRepository extends JpaRepository<DBFile, String> {
    List<DBFile> findByDescription(String description);
}
```

Comment: Why? I needed incomplete match of query, so I used the official documentation on JPA - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: But still, tried as you advised and got the same exception

Comment: The cause in the stacktrace is Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() is not yet implemented., apply this solution github Postgresql project https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1102#issuecomment-398036270